# how do I show stack trace in Linux?

Tags: c++, stack-trace, g++4.9

I am using g++ 4.9.2 on Solaris 10 as well as on Linux. I am using a signal handler. Whenever there is a signal, I would like to show the stack trace.
How do I show the stack trace in Linux?

Comment: Solaris or Linux?

Answer (score 2):

In principle, a signal handler can only call a (small) set of functions, only the so called *async-signal safe functions* (which excludes `backtrace` from GNU libc, as suggested by [Maxim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42281696/841108)). Read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

In practice, especially if you only want to show a backtrace and then abort, you might not care. Look also into Ian Taylor's [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace) which parses DWARF debug information (so you'll better compile your code with `-g` flag to `gcc` or `g++`, perhaps in addition of optimization flags like `-O2`). Inside GCC it is practically used to dump a nice backtrace on bad signals (including segmentation faults, i.e. `SIGSEGV`) from their signal handlers and works quite well most of the time. You should then use a recent version of GCC, e.g. GCC 6

Comment: Rather than inside gdb, I would like to print stack trace programatically

Comment: But the solution I am suggesting in programatical (`gdb` is not involved). However, you'll better compile with `-g`

Answer (score 1):

There is [`backtrace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace_symbols.3.html) family of functions that do that. See the man page for examples.